# How to group combined AND with OR statements using the Sequel GEM in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel

I am fairly good at PHP (OOP & flat). And for the past year or so I have been tasked with maintaining a Ruby codebase; a skill I am still learning. I am not too clear on how to properly structure a filtering chain using Sequel so `AND` as well `OR` statements can be properly contained.

This is the MySQL query structure I want to have:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_objects`
WHERE (
  (
    ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959)) OR ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
  )
  OR
  ((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959))
  AND
  (NOT `datebegin` = 0) AND (NOT `dateend` = 0)
)
;
```

And this is the Sequel code fragment I am using:

```
some_objects = where{((datebegin >= start_year) & (datebegin <= end_year)) | ((dateend >= start_year) & (dateend <= end_year))}.
               or{(datebegin <= start_year) & (dateend >= end_year)}.
               where(~:datebegin => 0, ~:dateend => 0)
```

And this is what I am actually getting:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_objects`
WHERE (
  (
    ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959)) OR ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
    OR
    ((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959))
  )
  AND
  (NOT `datebegin` = 0) AND (NOT `dateend` = 0)
)
;
```

I have also tried different variations on the same Sequel code such as this:

```
some_objects = where(:datebegin => start_year..end_year).
               or(:dateend => start_year..end_year).
               or{|o|(o.datebegin <= start_year) & (o.dateend >= end_year)}.
               where(~:datebegin => 0, ~:dateend => 0)
```

And this:

```
some_objects = where(:datebegin => start_year..end_year).
               or(:dateend => start_year..end_year).
               or{(datebegin <= start_year) & (dateend >= end_year)}.
               where(~:datebegin => 0, ~:dateend => 0)
```

But I still end up with the first SQL structure where this whole chunk is basically `((AND OR AND OR))`:

```
(
  ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959)) OR ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
  OR
  ((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959))
)
```

When I want `((AND OR AND) OR)`:

```
(
  ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959)) OR ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
)
OR
((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959))
```

Comment: Would using the `BETWEEN` operator make this easier? That cuts down on the number of `AND` cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your initial query is that you are depending on the OR/AND precedence rules instead of using explicit parentheses.  Your initial query could be expressed as:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_objects`
WHERE (
  ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959))
  OR
  ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
  OR
  ((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959) AND (NOT `datebegin` = 0) AND (NOT `dateend` = 0))
)
```

You could express this in Sequel as:

```
DB[:some_objects].where{((datebegin >= start_year) & (datebegin <= end_year)) | ((dateend >= start_year) & (dateend <= end_year))}.
  or{((datebegin <= start_year) & (dateend >= end_year)) & Sequel.negate(:datebegin => 0)}
```

Which yields the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_objects` WHERE (
  ((`datebegin` >= 1950) AND (`datebegin` <= 1959))
  OR
  ((`dateend` >= 1950) AND (`dateend` <= 1959))
  OR
  ((`datebegin` <= 1950) AND (`dateend` >= 1959) AND (`datebegin` != 0))
)
```

This should perform the same as the SQL you used, but it is a bit more readable (e.g. `datebegin != 0` instead of `NOT datebegin = 0`). Note that you don't need the `NOT dateend = 0` filter, because it is a subset of the `dateend >= 1959` filter.

Comment: You apparently didn't read the end of my post.  You don't need the `NOT date_end = 0` condition, as it is a subset of the `dateend >= 1959` condition.  But if you really wanted to add a pointless condition: `Sequel.negate(:datebegin => 0, :dateend => 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Remember with Sequel if you're really up against the wall, just spell out your conditions the hard way:

```
records = where(%Q[
  (
    (`datebegin` >= 1950 AND `datebegin` <= 1959)
    OR (`dateend` >= 1950 AND `dateend` <= 1959)
  )
  OR (`datebegin` <= 1950 AND `dateend` >= 1959)
])
```

Those "zero" dates are kind of annoying from a query perspective, they'd be better off as `NULL` so they wouldn't need to be excluded here. Since `NULL` is never greater than, less than, or equal to anything, it's invisible to these queries. Zero, on the other hand, is a valid number and has to be excluded.

As an example of how this works with ranges:

```
records = where(datebegin: (1950..1959)).or(dateend: (1950..1959))
```

Those are expressed with the `BETWEEN` operator. From an indexing perspective that's usually at least a little faster than a bounded range using `AND`.

Comment: No need to get all testy. Your query is really hard to follow and I'm doing my best. I've just edited it. I'd hope it's pretty obvious you can put your SQL in there as-is and it'll work.

Comment: The nice thing about Sequel is it'll just do what you tell it to, but it has some convenience methods that make it easier to describe that. When those fail, do it the hard way. The [documentation on filtering](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html) goes into more detail.

Comment: Using string interpolation is [asking for trouble](http://bobby-tables.com/). That's why there's support for data placeholders like `?` where they're not named, or `:name` where they are. Normally you can do this with binding like `where('datebegin > :start_year', start_year: 1950)` or something like that. I'm not sure if you can use the same placeholder more than once, but you can try. The first few examples in that linked documentation go into more detail.

Comment: Obviously the best way to find out is to run it interactively. Remember you can always append `.sql` on the end to see what is intending to do. There's no mystery here unlike with ActiveRecord.